# Can't import bulma carousel into GatsbyJS project

Tags: gatsby, bulma

I'm trying to import [bulma-carousel](https://creativebulma.net/product/carousel/demo#) into my GatsbyJS project, but I'm having a lot of difficulty getting it to work. I'm working with the [gatsby-bulma-quickstart](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/amandeepmittal/gatsby-bulma-quickstart/) which also comes with a `Helmet`. In the Helmet component, I inserted the script and style tag like this:

```
<link href="bulma-carousel/dist/css/bulma-carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel.min.js"></script>
```

and these files exist in the `node-modules` folder when running `yarn add bulma-carousel`. From there, I used the `useEffect` React hook in my `layout.js` like this:

```
import bulmaCarousel from 'bulma-carousel/dist/js/bulma-carousel';
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    bulmaCarousel.attach();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet />
      <Portfolio />
    </div>
  )
};
```

I later put the example code inside my `Portfolio` component, but the carousel doesn't function at all. Would anyone know if I'm missing something important? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have met similar difficulties and ended up downgrading from bulma-carousel 4.x to "3.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you attach bulmaCarousel you are supposed to supply the ID of the carousel as in the docs example:

```
bulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-demo', {
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            slidesToShow: 4
        });
```